# Selection of differentially expressed genes

Tags: r, computational-statistics, bioinformatics, sequence-analysis

I don't have any statistical background. Have some questions.

I see in some research papers they select differentially expressed genes based on fold change and p.value. And in some other papers I see they select based on foldchange and FDR (p.value adjusted). In other papers they just do t-test and based on p-value < 0.05 they select significant genes.

1) Could you please explain which one of the above is more stringent for differential analysis? And why?

2) What is the main difference between those analysis?